# Hive: Extracting sub-string from / separated column

Tags: regex, database, hive, hiveql

My table has entries entries like:

```
this/is/my/dir/file
this/is/my/another/dir/file
```

I want to display the string without the /filename:

```
this/is/my/dir
```

This is my code:

```
select regexp_replace(filepath,'[^/]+[/]$','')
```

Comment: You had the right thought, just backwards. `[/][^/]+$`, or more simply, `\/[^/]+$`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
select regexp_replace(filepath,'/[^/]+$','')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uagVff/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%2F%5B%5E%2F%5D%2B%24):

[image]

**Regex details**

- `/` - a `/` char
- `[^/]+` - 1+ chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score -1):

Here, we can use an expression likely similar to:

```
(.+)(\/.+)
```

and our code might look like:

```
select regexp_replace(filepath,'^(.+)(\/.+)$','$1')
```

or

```
select regexp_replace(filepath,'(.+)(\/.+)','$1')
```

Our desired output is in the first capturing group `$1`, followed by the last slash and filename, in the second capturing group `$2`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1fyiyZ/1/)